# How to display my database entries on the Barryvdh\DomPDF\wrapper in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

l have successifully intergrated the Barryvdh\DomPDF\wrapper on my laravel 5.2 project and can generate a pdf from the hard coded data inside the PdfController, but now l want to display data for the clicked entry from the database for example l have data for my patients so l want to generate a profile for each patient on pdf...

my pdfcontroller is like

```
   namespace hospital\Http\Controllers;

   use Barryvdh\DomPDF\wrapper;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use hospital\Http\Requests;
   use hospital\Models\Entry;

  class PdfController extends Controller
  {
    public function invoice() 
{


    $data = $this->getData();
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $invoice = "2222";
    $view =  \View::make('pdf.invoice', compact('data', 'date', 'invoice'))->render();
    $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHTML($view);
    return $pdf->stream('invoice');
}


public function getData() 
{
    $data =  [
        'quantity'      => '1' ,
        'description'   => 'some random text',
        'price'   => '500',
        'total'     => '500'
    ];
    return $data;
}
```

}

So l want fill the getData function with info from database with my entry information for example lam lam rendering a profile for each patient by this code in my Entry controller

```
   public function show($id)
     {
     $entry = Entry::find($id);

     return view('entry.show')->with('entry', $entry);
```

}